# Using React / JSX for Non-JavaScript Code Generation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-generation, jsx

I was wondering if you could use React/JSX in a code generation framework.

Is there a way to do something like the code below in JSX?

```
var className = "Person"
return (
     //// public class {className} 
     //// {
     ////
     //// }
);
```

Where the //// would be some special character or character sequence that signals to JSX parser that this should just be plain text?

Or is there a better approach using React that already exists?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm guessing you could just treat everything as strings and manipulate strings with react.  Not pretty but it should work.  But like BuddyJoe said, what exactly are you trying to accomplish

Comment: Loop over JSON files that comes from a variety of sources and use a template type approach to output code in things like C#, Java, SQL, Elixir, etc... I have written this before in other languages but now in porting it to JavaScript I am wondering if JSX could play a role in the templating. I love the in-line approach of things like this and C#s Razor.

Comment: T4 tempalting from Microsoft is nice... but very Microsoft specific. Looking to do something more "open" and ubiquitous (like JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in the browser you can do something like this and then grab the textContent of the `<code>` element that was rendered when it mounts.  I haven't used React on the server but I'm guessing you could use [ReactDOMSever's renderToString](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) and then create a simple script that strips the opening and closing tags from your string and you have your code in a text string that you could save to anytype of file using node.

```
var data = {
  class_name : 'User',
  method1Name: 'doSomething'
}


class MakeClass extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
     console.log(this.codeElem.textContent)
  }

  render() {
     let {json} = this.props;
    return (
      <code ref={c=>this.codeElem=c}>{`

class ${json.class_name} {
  constructor() {
      // do something
  }

  ${json.method1Name}() {
    // this method does something
  }
}

      `}</code>
    )
  }
}

 ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(MakeClass, {json: data}), 
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

You can see the full thing here:
http://jsbin.com/rizaqifasi/edit?html,js,console,output